# Reading form address bar in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email, get

I am trying to read email value from address bar in my active.php page
my address bar looks like this.

```
"mywebsite/foledr/?page_id=734?email=emailaddress"
```

now in my active.php page I write

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, to assign emailaddress into $email. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `?` is the start of the query string, while `&` separates the key=value pairs.

You have `"mywebsite/folder/?page_id=734?email=emailaddress"`

Which should be `"mywebsite/folder/?page_id=734&email=emailaddress"`
 using a `&` inbetween the `page_id=734` and `email=emailaddress`

Answer (score 5):

`?` *starts* the query string.

`&` is used to separate the key=value pairs in it

You only have a `page_id` key, its value is `734?email=emailaddress`.

Don't use `?` when you mean `&`.